# Help regarding an iteration formula

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Consider the mapping $$ (a,b,c,d) \mapsto  \left(\frac{a+b}{2}, \frac{b+c}{2},\frac{c+d}{2},\frac{d+a}{2}\right );a,b,c,d \in \mathcal{R^+}$$
Intuitively it is obvious that the if the above mapping is applied  iteratively, some that    is halving the sum of two neighbouring    quantities while keeping the overall  total equal which is $a+b+c+d.$  So , it is expected that the iteration process should  in the limit in the result in the tuple  $(av,av,av,av)$ where $$ av=\frac{\sum a}{4}.$$ However, unfortunately ,I am not able to put this into a formal argument.Would somebody kindly help?ANy help will be greatly appreciated.

PS:-There is nothing peculiar with 4.Any other number of quntities can be taken in the tuple

Comment: First you have to prove that the itering sequence converges. And after you can apply limits arguments to find your $v$.

Comment: That ios exactly what i haveno idea about

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Proof**

Beginning by defining the iterating sequences

\begin{split}
X_n& \triangleq(w_n,x_n,y_n,z_n) \to \left(\frac{w_n+x_n}{2},\frac{x_n+y_n}{2},\frac{y_n+z_n}{2},\frac{z_n+w_n}{2}\right) \\
X_0 & = (a,b,c,d)
\end{split}

So considering :

$$ f (w,x,y,z) \to \left(\frac{w+x}{2},\frac{x+y}{2},\frac{y+z}{2},\frac{z+w}{2}\right) $$

$$ X_{n+1} =f(X_n) $$

Yet, for all $(w,x,y,z)$

$$ Df(w,x,y,z) : H=(h_1,h_2,h_3,h_4) \to \begin{pmatrix} \dfrac{1}{2} & 0  &0 & \dfrac{1}{2}\\ \dfrac{1}{2} & \dfrac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \dfrac{1}{2} & \dfrac{1}{2} & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \dfrac{1}{2} & \dfrac{1}{2}\end{pmatrix}H $$

It follows that for all $(w,x,y,z)$

$$ ||| Df(w,x,y,z) |||_{\infty}\triangleq\sup_{||H||\neq 0} \dfrac{||Df(w,x,y,z)(H)||}{||H||}=1/2<1 $$

So by Banach-Picard theorem, it exists one and only one fixed point for $X_n$ sequence whatever $X_0$ (finite) is. Then by component combination every $w_n,x_n,y_n,z_n$ sequences converge.

I let you end the proof to show the unique limit for every of them.

Comment: what are $h_i's$

Comment: They are the fourth components of $H$ parameter of the differential of $f$ at the point $(w,x,y,z)$ : remember the differential of a function at one point is a function .

Comment: I edited the matrix.

Comment: Note that that is *not* a contraction, $1$ is an eigenvalue of that matrix. It is unclear to me how you can apply the Banach fixed-point theorem, perhaps I am overlooking something?

Comment: Actually yes I modified the matrix I have to modify the differential

Answer (score 1):

Let $(a_n, b_n, c_n, d_n)$ be the quadruple after the $n$-th iteration, where $(a_0, b_0, c_0, d_0)$ are the initial values and can be arbitrary real numbers, the restriction to positive numbers is not necessary.

Without loss of generality we can assume that $a_0+b_0+c_0+d_0 = 0$, and consequently $a_n+b_n+c_n+d_n = 0$ for all $n$.

Then
$$
\begin{align}
 a_{n+1}^2+b_{n+1}^2+c_{n+1}^2+d_{n+1}^2
 &= \frac 12 \left( a_n^2+b_n^2+c_n^2+d_n^2 + a_nb_n+b_nc_n+c_nd_n + d_n a_n\right) \\
&= \frac 12 \left( a_n^2+b_n^2+c_n^2+d_n^2 + (a_n+c_n)(b_n+d_n)\right) \\
 &= \frac 12 \left( a_n^2+b_n^2+c_n^2+d_n^2 - (a_n+c_n)^2\right) \\
 &\le \frac 12 \left( a_n^2+b_n^2+c_n^2+d_n^2  \right) \, .
\end{align}
$$

It follows that
$$
 \lim_{n\to \infty} a_n^2+b_n^2+c_n^2+d_n^2 = 0
$$
and that implies that the four sequences $(a_n)$, $(b_n)$, $(c_n)$, $(d_n)$ converge to zero.

---

*Generalization for iterations of tuples with arbitrary length:*

For fixed $m \ge 2$, let $(x_{n,1}, x_{n,2}, \ldots, x_{n,m})$ be the tuple after the $n$-th iteration of the initial tuple $(x_{0,1}, x_{0,2}, \ldots, x_{0,m})$. Again we assume that $x_{0,1} + x_{0,2} +\cdots + x_{0,m} = 0$.

In order to prove that
$$
 \lim_{n \to \infty} x_{n,1}^2 + x_{n,2}^2 +\cdots + x_{n,m}^2 = 0
$$
and consequently $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_{n, j} = 0$ for all $1 \le j \le m$, it suffices to prove the following

> **Lemma:** Let $m \ge 2$ and $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_m \in \Bbb R$  with $x_1 + x_2 + \ldots + x_m = 0$. Set $x_{m+1} = x_1$. Then
> $$
>  \sum_{j=1}^m \left( \frac{x_j + x_{j+1}}{2}\right)^2 \le C_m \sum_{j=1}^m x_j^2
> $$
> with a constant $0 < C_m < 1$ which depends only on $m$.

*Proof:* Set $S=\sum_{j=1}^m x_j^2$ and $S' = \sum_{j=1}^m \left( \frac{x_j + x_{j+1}}{2}\right)^2$. If $S=0$ then $S' = 0$, so from now on we assume that $S > 0$.
$$ \tag{*}
 S' - S = \sum_{j=1}^m \left( \frac{x_j + x_{j+1}}{2}\right)^2
 - \sum_{j=1}^m\frac{x_j^2+x_{j+1}^2}{2}
 = -\frac 14 \sum_{j=1}^m (x_j - x_{j+1})^2
$$
which already shows that $S' \le S$. But we need a slightly better estimate.

There must be (at least) one index $j$ with $|x_k| \ge \sqrt{\frac Sm}$, and since the sum of all $x_j$ is zero, there must be another index $l$ such that $x_k$ and $x_l$ have opposite sign. It follows that there is an index $j$ with $|x_j - x_{j+1}| \ge \frac 1m \sqrt{\frac Sm}$. This gives a negative upper bound for the right-hand side in $(*)$, and we get
$$
 S \le S - \frac 14 \frac{S}{m^3} = \left( 1 - \frac{1}{4m^3}\right) S \, .
$$
This proves the lemma.

Comment: Can you help me understand this? If you start with $(1,1,0,0)$, the next step is $ (1,.5,0,.5)$ so the max and min didn't change.

Comment: @3rdMoment: There is no explanation, my answer was embarrassingly wrong. I have rewritten it completely now, hopefully this version is correct! Thanks for your feedback

Comment: @MartinR Actually I think considering $a_0+b_0+c_0+d_0=0$ is not without loss of generality a priori because if you take $a_0=b_0=c_0=d_0>0$, you have a constant sequence and the hypothesis cannot be made, and if you suppose the sum is an arbitrary real, things are not obvious at least for me if I don't mistake.

Comment: @EDX: Let $x = (a_0+b_0+c_0+d_0)/4$ be the average of the initial values, and consider the modified sequence $(a_n', b_n', c_n', d_n')$ for the initial values $(a_0', b_0', c_0', d_0') = (a_0-x,b_0-x, c_0-x, d_0-x)$. Then $a_0'+ b_0'+ c_0'+ d_0' = 0$ and $(a_n', b_n', c_n', d_n') = (a_n-x,b_n-x, c_n-x, d_n-x)$ for all $n$, so $a_n' \to 0$ implies $a_n \to x$, etc.

Comment: @EDX: In other words, if the initial values $(a_0, b_0, c_0, d_0)$ are shifted by a common value $x$ then all iterates $(a_n, b_n, c_n, d_n)$ are shifted by the same number $x$. Therefore we can shift the initial values so that their sum is equal to zero.

Comment: Ok thanks. I will see if I can complete my answer through a analytic differential approach.